# Create file and persist environment variable via Amazon EC2 User Data script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a small confusion regarding the `userdata` that can be made available to an AWS machine during instance creation. So I have a bash script where I am generating a file as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Creating a file" >> /files/test.txt
export MY_VARIABLE=/files/test.txt
```

Now I pass this script as the userdata variable when using the `boto3` ec2 instance creation as:

```
import boto3
ec2 = s.resource('ec2')

with open('script.sh', r) as file:
    user_data = file.read()
res = ec2.create_instances(... UserData=user_data)
```

Am I correct in assuming that the file and the environment variable created through the script will be available to the created instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The User Data script runs as the `root` user when the instance boots for the first time.

It is likely that there is no `/files/` directory on the instance, so the file creation would fail. You should create that directory first.

The `EXPORT` probably won't work because the script is being run as `root`, whereas you will normally login as `ec2-user`. To persist an environment variable for a user, you would need to add it to a **profile** file.

See: [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117470/130465)